# ASP.NET using identity, authenticate against a different pre-identity membership database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity, asp.net-membership

I'm trying to share logins in a new version of ASP.NET website which uses identity, with an existing older website whose membership database is pre-identity (ASP.NET Membership). The first hurdle I hit was that there is no Migrations table, and I'm not finding much information to determine if I can even do this. How do I authenticate effectively with that database? I can't control the other web application at all, except to ask them to match my MachineKey.

Clarification: The domains are completely different, but they share the same back-end database, so cookie-based solutions won't work.

Answer (score 0):

This [microsoft documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/cookie.html) should get you something to start with.

I don't get why Cookie based solution will not work for you if you have access to the database. Firstly, You query and validate the user details with the existing database separately and then set the Cookie based on the result of the first operation.

This [video](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/03/15/get-started-with-asp-net-core-authorization-part-1-of-2/) provides good insights to the new ASP Core Authorization. I've provided a code snippet from one of their [sample applications](https://github.com/blowdart/AspNetAuthorizationWorkshop) that explains the solution that I'm suggesting.

```
    IUserRepository _userRepository;

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string userName, string password, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        if (!_userRepository.ValidateLogin(userName, password))
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Invalid Login";
            return View();
        }

        await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("Cookie", _userRepository.Get(userName),
            new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20),
                IsPersistent = false,
                AllowRefresh = false
            });

        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync("Cookie");

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Comment: Edited the question to clarify that they are different domains.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I had thought you were inferring the browser would carry the cookie across to the other site. I'll review tonight and if it works will mark the answer, I hope it is! :)